# ASP insert don't work, error 404 with IIS WinServer2012

Tags: iis, asp-classic, insert

I have a problem in my asp code which I can't seem to fix. I want to do an insert but it doesn't work. I really don't understand why my select query works perfectly but not my insert.
I don't know if it's a syntax error or what.

This is my code:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
    dim ajoutChamp1
    ajoutChamp1 = request.form("ajoutChamp1")
    Response.Write(ajoutChamp1)
    if len(ajoutChamp1 ) > 0 then
        set dbcon2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        dbcon2.open "dsn=bdd"
        rqt2="insert into Table1(Champ1) values ('1');"
        set info=dbcon.execute(rqt2)
        Response.Write(rqt2)
        dbcon2.close
        dbcon2 =null    
    end if
%>
<html>    
    <body>
        <h1>Mon App ASP<h1>
        <h2>Données lues dans la bd : bdd.mdb</h2>
        <h3>Table : table1</h3>
        <h4>Lecture :</h4>
        <table>
        <%
            set dbcon=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            dbcon.open "dsn=bdd"
            rqt="select * from Table1;"
            set info=dbcon.execute (rqt)
            if not info.eof then
                %><tr><th><%=info("Champ1")%></th></tr><%
                info.movenext    
            end if    
            while not info.eof
                %><tr><td><%=info("Champ1")%></td></tr><%
                info.movenext
            wend
            info=null
            dbcon.close
            dbcon =null
        %>
        </table>
        <h4>Ajout :</h4>
          <form method="post" action="">     
            <input name="ajoutChamp1" type="text"> <input type="submit">     
              </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark as approved if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm right, but in this piece of code:

```
if len(ajoutChamp1 ) > 0 then
    set dbcon2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbcon2.open "dsn=bdd"
    rqt2="insert into Table1(Champ1) values ('1');"
    set info=dbcon.execute(rqt2)
    Response.Write(rqt2)
    dbcon2.close
    dbcon2 =null    
end if
```

`dbcon2` is created (instantiated) but you're using `dbcon` to execute your `INSERT`.

Comment: It was a problem of version by posting my code, now i change it to dbcon2 but it's not working .. :(
Someone have a other idea ?

Comment: JimmyP74, please edit your code to show us current version.

Answer (score 0):

I find my problem, it was that the right of modification on the folder of my database to the groupe Everyone was missing.